# Find Header Based on Cell Value

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have the followin data:

[image]

What I want is to get the headers of every cell that contains the value 1 like this:

[image]

I tried `INDEX(F9:J9;;MATCH(1;F10:J10;0))` but this one only gets the header of the first value 1. What can I do for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This can be solved using `TEXTJOIN` Excel formula:*

**N.B.** *TEXTJOIN is available with Excel 2016 & higher versions, also with Office 365.*

But you can create similar Function using VBA macro.

**How it works:**

- **C**opy below shown VBA code.
- Press `Alt+F11` to open VB Editor.
- **I**nsert a new **M**odule (Press Alt+I+M).
- **P**aste the VBA code.
- **S**ave workbook as **M**acro enabled.

---

```
    Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr)
    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arr2()
    Dim t As Long, y As Long
    t = -1
    y = -1
    If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
        arr2 = arr.Value
    Else
        arr2 = arr
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    t = UBound(arr2, 2)
    y = UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
        For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
            For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    Else
        For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim))
    End Function
```

---

[image]

- An array (CSE) formula in cell `B7`, finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** and fill down.

`{=TEXTJOIN(":",1,IF(B2:F2=1,B$1:F$1,""))}`

- *Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: This is amazing really. Thank you very much!

Comment: @JamesKando,, glad to help you,, keep asking ☺